# Labelling Vertices of a GraphicsComplex

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, labeling

I cannot figure out how to label the vertices of a `GraphicsComplex`, for example

```
Graphics3D[
     GraphicsComplex[{{1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {-1, 0,1}},
        {Polygon[{2, 4, 5}], Polygon[{1, 3, 4}], Polygon[{1, 2, 3}]}]]
```

I've seen that this can be done for `Graph` and `GraphPlot` using `VertexLabelling`, but as far as I know, there isn't a similar option for `GraphicsComplex`.

Comment: You've seen `Text[]`? `GraphicsComplex[pts, Text[#, #] & /@ pts]`

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on comment from Guess who it is, I think he pretty much had it nailed but instead of mapping onto `pts` I believe you need to use `Range[Length[pts]]`.

`GraphicsComplex` will use the point number to indicate the position of the graphic object.

```
With[
 {
  pts = {{1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}}
  },
 Graphics3D[{
   Opacity[0.5],
   GraphicsComplex[pts,
    {
     Red, Polygon[{2, 4, 5}],
     Blue, Polygon[{1, 3, 4}],
     Green, Polygon[{1, 2, 3}],
     }
    ],
   Opacity[1],
   Black,
   GraphicsComplex[pts,
    Text[Style[ToString[#], Background -> White, 16], #] & 
      /@ Range[Length[pts]]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

This makes a plot that looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

You can also post-process the `Graphics3D` output to add the labels:

```
g0 = Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[{{1, -1, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}},
  {Polygon[{2, 4, 5}], Polygon[{1, 3, 4}], Polygon[{1, 2, 3}]}]];

Insert[g0, Text[Style[#, 24, Background -> Yellow], #] & /@ 
  Range[Length @ g0[[1, 1]]], {1, 2, 1}]
```

[image]